# Put text in 2 textboxes in other location at same time

Tags: vb.net

Hey i want to insert text in 2 different textboxes and also inside tags

So i have a empty Textbox and when you click on my button it will do this:

```
    Dim myNum As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myNum = InputBox("Please input a Color code. Dont forget the # for the code Example: #000000")
    Dim insertText = "[color=" + myNum + "]" + "[/color]"
    Dim insertText2 = "<font color=" + DubbelQ + myNum + DubbelQ + "></font>"
    Dim insertPos As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart

    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Insert(insertPos, insertText2)
    TextBox2.SelectionStart = insertPos + insertText2.Length
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(insertPos, insertText)
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = insertPos + insertText.Length
End Sub
```

But it doesnt work when i Want to add another color inside an Tag ] here [

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using the SelectionStart of the first textbox on the second textbox.
You need to find a way to compute the correct insertion point for thextbox2 if you want it to work fine.

based on the different lengths of your tags, you need to use insertPos+6 for the second text box.

try this code:

```
Dim DubbelQ As String = """"
Dim myNum As String
Dim NumberOfColorTags As Integer = 0  
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myNum = InputBox("Please input a Color code. Dont forget the # for the code Example: #000000")
    Dim insertText = " [color=" + myNum + "]" + "[/color]"
    Dim insertText2 = "<font color=" + DubbelQ + myNum + DubbelQ + "></font>"
    Dim insertPos As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim insertPos2 As Integer = insertPos += (6 * NumberOfColorTags)

    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Insert(insertPos2, insertText2)
    TextBox2.SelectionStart = insertPos2 + insertText2.Length
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(insertPos, insertText)
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = insertPos + insertText.Length
    NumberOfColorTags++
End Sub
```

Comment: On second thought, you will need to add 6 for each tag. to do that you will need a counter. so I've edited my answer to have that counter.

Comment: thanks alot but i get some errors on indertpos2 and NumberOfColorTags++ and on += (6 * NumberOfColorTags) Errors are: Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses 4 expression is not a method 6 expression expected

Comment: I fixed the error on += (6 * NumberOfColorTags) it has to be =+ instead of += so not InsertPos2 is also fixed

Comment: Well, it's been a while since my vb.net days, but I'm pretty sure it should support the += and ++ operators.
If not, you can always write it the long way:
insertPos = insertPos + (6 * NumberOfColorTags)

and 

NumberOfColorTags = NumberOfColorTags + 1